# style.css of child theme is not overwriting parents style.css for .box

Tags: child-theme

I am using latest wordpres. I have created child theme.

I am trying to overwride the .box style of parent theme but it is not overriding it. If i do this in parent themes `style.css` it works.

```
//This is style.css of child theme
/*
Theme Name: Custom Theme
Description: Child Theme
Author: Shahrukh
Template: basetheme
Version: 0.1
*/
.box {
    width: 600px;
    max-width: 75%;
    /* padding: 4rem; */
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: solid 1px #fff;
    border: solid 1px hsla(0, 0%, 100%, .3);
}
```

This is function.php of child theme

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',array('parent-style') );
}

require get_stylesheet_directory() . '/myGallery/gallery_functions_include.php';

?>
```

Comment: do you see these 2 stylesheets in the HTML source ?

Answer (score 1):

Is this: **/**  just overwritten or is it a mistake in your code? `max-width: 75%;/`

It might cause to not work properly. Otherwise i will try a bit shady way, try to make your parent attributes `!important`.

Answer (score 0):

I actully figured out the problem. I did not want the padding porperty i.e `padding: 4rem;`.
So instead of overriding it in child them as `padding: 0rem;` I did not mention it.
Therefore that property was not being overridden.